# Increase text cursor/insertion point size in Pages

Tags: macos, pages, accessibility

The thin line of the text insertion cursor is nearly impossible to see on a page of text. In order to find it, I have to "enter" and then hope I correctly maintained my count to move it from word to word as I edit. I have the mouse cursor enlarged which is nice but I need a way to increase the width or general visibility of the text insertion cursor in Pages.

Is there any way to make it wider? I know it is possible on word, it just seems silly to not have something so simple in Pages (considering how far, deep, and complicated some of the other accessibility options get).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't agree more. What ever happened to the good old "blinking block" insertion point cursors of 40+ years ago? But I have a work-around.

What I do to find the insertion point in TextEdit, Pages, and any other standard text entry interface like composing a message in Mail, is hold down "shift" and type the left-arrow key. That selects text going backwards from the insertion point, without changing anything, but since it highlights the text it is instantly visible. To put everything back the way it was, let go of "shift" and type a right-arrow.

Note if the insertion point is not on the currently displayed page, shift-left-arrow causes TextEdit and Pages (at least) to first jump to the page with the insertion point.

Of course, as with everything in life, there's an exception: it doesn't work if the insertion point is at the beginning of the document. So, try shift-right-arrow if shift-left-arrow doesn't work.